# How can i write inner query in spring boot jpa

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa

My query is this :

> SELECT * FROM property_data p JOIN (SELECT property_id, MAX(date) AS
>   MaxDateTime FROM property_data WHERE property_id IN (18255, 80604,
>   35983, 41220)GROUP BY property_id) groupedtt ON p.property_id =
>   groupedtt.property_id AND p.date = groupedtt.MaxDateTime AND
>   p.property_id IN (18255, 80604, 35983, 41220);

I have written in this form:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM DateWisePropertyInfo p JOIN (SELECT h.property_id, MAX(h.date) AS MaxDateTime FROM DateWisePropertyInfo h WHERE h.property_id IN :hIds GROUP BY h.property_id) p.groupedtt ON p.property_id = groupedtt.property_id AND p.date = groupedtt.MaxDateTime AND p.property_id IN :hIds")
List<DateWisePropertyInfo> findByLatestDateAndPropertyIdIn(@Param("hIds") List<Long> propertyIds);
```

Detailed Error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 81 [SELECT p FROM com.oyorooms.retention.entity.primary.DateWisePropertyInfo p JOIN (SELECT h.property_id, MAX(h.date) AS MaxDateTime FROM com.oyorooms.retention.entity.primary.DateWisePropertyInfo h WHERE h.property_id IN :hIds GROUP BY h.property_id) p.groupedtt ON p.property_id = groupedtt.property_id AND p.date = groupedtt.MaxDateTime AND p.property_id IN :hIds]
```

But this is not working, throwing InvocationTargetException.

Comment: You may paste the error stacktrace here

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 81 [SELECT p FROM com.oyorooms.retention.entity.primary.DateWisePropertyInfo p JOIN (SELECT h.property_id, MAX(h.date) AS MaxDateTime FROM com.oyorooms.retention.entity.primary.DateWisePropertyInfo h WHERE h.property_id IN :hIds GROUP BY h.property_id) p.groupedtt ON p.property_id = groupedtt.property_id AND p.date = groupedtt.MaxDateTime AND p.property_id IN :hIds]

Comment: yes, i have re-written my query in subquery form. and it solved the case.